# JSON.parse exception when copy & pasting stringified objects with escaped quotes

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I have to stringify some JS objects to save the text somewhere and I'd like to be able to copy the saved text manually afterwards and pass it via the console to a function which then parses the text to do something with the original object.

Unfortunately parsing pasted text seems to have problems with escaped double quotes since parsing always fails.

I have created a small snippet which illustrates my problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/wgwLcgz6/1/

```
var jsonStr = JSON.stringify({ arg1: 'some string "with quotes"' });

$('#out1').html(jsonStr); // {"arg1":"some string \"with quotes\""}
JSON.parse(jsonStr); // Works just fine
try {
    // Copied the ouput of JSON.stringify manually and pasted it directly into
    // the parse function...
    JSON.parse('{"arg1":"some string \"with quotes\""}');

    // We never get here since an exception is thrown
    $('#out2').html('Parsed successfully');
} catch (ex) {
    // SyntaxError: Unexpected token w
    $('#out2').html(ex.toString());
}
```

I think I do understand why this is happening even though I can't explain it properly but I don't have any idea on how to circumvent this and would really appreciate some help and maybe deeper explanation.

One more thing: If I paste the stringified object `{"arg1":"some string \"with quotes\""}` into an online json parser like http://jsonlint.com/ it parses it just fine which I guess is because they use there own parser instead of the browsers built in ones...

Comment: The JSON standard does not permit "control characters" such as a tab or newline. Refer http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape quotes and backslashes. Since you're using single quotes around a string with double quotes, you just have to escape the backslashes:

```
JSON.parse('{"arg1":"some string \\"with quotes\\""}');
```

Comment: it helps me save my time.